# How to prevent edit game data JSON file in mobile game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making mobile 2D puzzle game by Unity
using LitJson, Save&Load game data by .json file (public data)

I made class Userdata, in the class there are money and items.. also read & write by json

But I don't want to edit this json file who downloaded apk

How to prevent this?

Comment: @Mateusz this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot completely protect data stored in the application. The most secure way to prevent players/ users from altering (save)game data, is to store them on a remote storage/database.

Taking database as an example, you could write PHP scripts which serve as middleman communicating between the database and your application.

In these scripts you would generally determine the logic and security handling on who gets to retrieve/ send what data to which table.

Comment: This does not necessarily has to be a database. It just has to be a remote storage with some proper networking logic behind it. Because even if you're storing something on a remote and just take every request granted, without checking, you might end up with something faking requests with mocked data in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use binary formter as it will save your data in binary encrypted formate.

while this still can be decrypted, but will minimize the chances for regular users

Edit: Binary formater is no longer secured to be used, use binary writer instead for data about monetizing.